# How to update a redux state from a node js function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, electron, serial-port

I'm creating a program that graphs in real time the data send by a serial port.
I'm using Electron, so in the main.js file (Where you create the window for the app) I have declared the event when receives data.

```
const { SerialPort, ReadlineParser } = require('serialport');

const port = new SerialPort({
  path: 'COM5',
  baudRate: 9600,
});
const parser = new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r\n' });
port.pipe(parser);
let anterior = '';
let cont = 0;
// on data print the complete data from the serial port
parser.on('data', (line) => {
  let value = line.substring(5, 15);

  value = parseFloat(value.trim());

  if (value > 0.0 && !line.includes('?') && line != anterior) {
    console.log(`> ${line}`);
    anterior = line;
    updateStateFromNode(value, cont);
    cont += 1;
  }
});
```

The function I call is this:

```
import { store } from '../store/store'; // my actual store
import { addValue, addLabel } from '../store/data';

function updateStateFromNode(newValue, newLabel) {
     store.dispatch(addValue(newValue));
     store.dispatch(addLabel(newLabel));
}
```

I console log inside the function addValue to check if it reaches the function, and it does...

I also have tried with a customHook, but it didn't work also.

Anyone knows how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main and renderer processes are isolated from each other, which means that dispatching from main will not update the store on your renderer. To communicate between the two processes, you can use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc). Assuming you use a preload file, you can do something looking like this:

**Main**

```
function updateStateFromNode(newValue, newLabel) {
  // We will use a channel named "updateState"
  mainWindow.webContents.send("updateState", newValue, newLabel);
}
```

**Preload**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronAPI", {
  onUpdateState: (callback) => {
    const channel = "updateState";
    const subscription = (_event, ...args) => callback(...args);

    // Sets the listener on the channel "updateState"
    ipcRenderer.on(channel, subscription);

    // Returns a function to remove the listener
    return () => {
      ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, subscription);
    };
  }
})
```

**Renderer**

```
import { addValue, addLabel } from "../store/data";

const { electronAPI } = window; // `electronAPI` is exposed with the preload

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Calls the function from preload to set the listener on the channel "updateState"
    const removeUpdateStateListener = electronAPI.onUpdateState((newValue, newLabel) => {
      dispatch(addValue(newValue));
      dispatch(addLabel(newLabel));
    });
    
    return removeUpdateStateListener; // Removes the listener on unmount
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (...);
}
```